# Function for plotting Julia Set

Tags: matlab, fractals

The [Julia set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set) is the set of complex numbers *z* that do not diverge under the following iteration:

$$ z = z^2 + c $$

Where *c* is a constant complex number.

Different values of *z* reach infinity at different rates. A colourful fractal is produced by colouring the complex plane based on the number of iterations required to reach infinity.

```
function colour = julia(c, total_iterations, image_size, limits)
%   Calculates julia set by iterating z = z^2 + c, where z and c are complex,
%   and recording when z reaches infinity.
%
%   Inputs:
%
%   c                   Fixed complex number, of form a + bi
%   total_iterations    Number of iterations of z = z^2 + c
%   image_size          2D vector with number of complex coordinates in 
%                           x and y directions  
%   limits              Vector with 4 elements: min x, max x, min y, max y
%
%   Outputs:
%
%   colour              Matrix of doubles, with size equal to image_size.
%                           Plotting this matrix will produce a julia set


im_step = (limits(4) - limits(3)) / (image_size(2) - 1);
re_step = (limits(2) - limits(1)) / (image_size(1) - 1);

reals = limits(1) : re_step : limits(2);            % Real numbers
imags = limits(3) : im_step : limits(4);            % Imaginary numbers
z = bsxfun(@plus, reals(:), (imags(:) * 1i)');      % Complex coordinates
colour = inf(size(z));                              % Colour of Julia set

for iteration = 1:total_iterations
    index = isinf(z);  
    % Only perform calculation on the z values that are less than infinity
    z(~index) = z(~index).^2 + c; 
    % Colour depends on number of iterations to reach infinity
    colour(index & isinf(colour)) = iteration;
end

colour = colour'; % Transpose so that plot will have reals on the x axis

end
```

Example:

```
image_size = [1000 1000];   % Image size
limits = [-1.5 1.5 -1 1];   % Real and imaginary limits
c = -0.4 + 0.6i;            % Fixed complex number
total_iterations = 300;

colour = julia(c, total_iterations, image_size, limits);

I = imagesc(colour);
colormap(hot)
myaa('publish')
```

Note: `myaa` is a [3rd party  anti-aliasing function](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20979-myaa-my-anti-alias-for-matlab).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very nice, well commented and well structured code!

Your comments in the start are exactly how they should be. You already know this, but I'll say it anyway. Writing a function where you have comments like this in the start aids the user because `help functionName` will provide the information needed in order to use the function.

---

There's is only one minor thing I would do differently. You know the end points, and how many steps there are. You have two options:

1. Calculate the step-size and use it to create a vector with the correct number of steps using colon
2. Just use what you know directly in linspace

Instead of calculating `re_step` and do `reals = limits(1) : re_step : limits(2);` you can use [`linspace`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html):

```
reals = linspace(limits(1), limits(2), image_size(1));
imags = linspace(limits(4), limits(3), image_size(2));
```

---

The following comment is incorrect: *"`% Transpose so that plot will have reals on the x axis`*"

You are working with complex numbers, and in those cases, `'` is the [complex conjugate transpose](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html), not the [regular transpose](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html). I don't know if you want the transpose or the complex conjugate transpose, but it's nice to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks Stewie, I tried to include your suggestions from last time. I didn't know about the transpose acting differently for complex numbers. Is there a reason you'd prefer linspace over using colons?

Comment: In this case, simplicity. You know the end points, and how many steps there are. You have two options: 1. Calculate the step-size and use it to create a vector with the correct number of steps using colon, or 2. Just use what you know directly in `linspace`.

Comment: That's a good point, it's more direct

Comment: r.e. the transpose: `colour` is a matrix of reals anyway (number of iterations) so don't think this note really applies, although it's worth being aware of. Also, you can avoid the `colour = colour';` line all together by using `z = bsxfun(@plus, reals', imags * 1i);` I think.